# Type inference question: Generic Method Argument to non-Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

First of all I know that the title is not so good but the thing is I dont even know how to explain my question; I'll just show an example below on what I'm trying to do:

**EDIT:** I should have given a better example to begin with; let's try again:

```
// MyAppComponentModel.dll
namespace MyAppComponentModel {
  using System.Collections;

  interface IResource { }
  interface IStringResource : IResource { }
  interface IIconResource : IResource { }
  interface IDialogResource : IResource { }
  interface IResourceProvider {
    void GetResource<T>(out T result, IDictionary criteria = null) where T : IResource;
  }
}

// ThirdPartyLib.dll
namespace ResourceProviderLibA {
  using System.Collections;
  using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
  using MyAppComponentModel.

  public sealed class StringResource : IStringResource { ... }
  public sealed class IconResource : IIconResource { ... }

  [Export(typeof(IResourceProvider))]
  public sealed class StringAndIconResourceProvider : IResourceProvider {
    void IResourceProvider.Get<T>(out T result, IDictionary criteria) {
      if (typeof(T) == typeof(IDialogResource))
        throw new NotSupportedException();

      this.InternalGet(out result, criteria);
    }

    void InternalGet(out IStringResource result, IDictionary criteria) {
      result = new StringResource();
      ...
    }

    void InternalGet(out IIconResource result, IDictionary criteria) {
      result = new IconResource();
      ...
    }
  }
}

// MyMefTestApp.exe
namespace MyMefTestApp {
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
  using MyAppComponentModel.

  static class Program {
    [ImportMany(typeof(IResourceProvider))]
    private IEnumerable<IResourceProvider> mProviders;

    static void Main(String[] args) {
      foreach (var provider in this.mProviders) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's somehow possible and I strongly believe I did something like this once just dont remember how. Anyone?

I already know that this can be done via Reflection so please skip those solutions - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as `T` can be anything (the compiler error actually is `cannot convert from 'out T' to 'out string'`), not just a `string` or `int`.

Just expose the `privateFoo` overloads as public `Foo` and be done with it, there is no other way as you can't restrict a generic to `string` or `int` (both are sealed, and a generic type constraint needs an interface or non sealed class).

**edit (changed question)**

If your Resource implementation only have parameterless constructors, I would use this (condensed example):

```
interface IHostProvider
{
  void Get<T> (out T result) where T : IHost,  new();
}

public interface IHost
{
}

public class Something : IHost
{
}

public class Provider : IHostProvider
{
  public void Get<T> (out T result) where T: IHost, new()
    {
      result = new T();
    }
}
```

If they require parameters however... phew, no idea this late at night. At first I had a static factory method in mind, but as you can't require a static method in an interface nor mark it abstract, this won't work either.

Comment: I've updated the example code to a more practical example; please take a look at it and see if it changes your answer in any way. I really need some help here or at least a "good programming" way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample seems to me impossible. Compiler can infer type arguments of method from known actual parameter types. For example:

```
void DoSomething<T>(T item)
{
    ...
}

IFoo foo =  default(IFoo);
DoSomething(foo); // void DoSomething<IFoo>(IFoo item);
```

But compiler can't do opposite. Compiler can't guess T's actual type and that's why it can't select applicable method overload.

```
void DoSomething(IFoo foo)
{
    ...
}

T item = default(T);
DoSomething(item); // won't compile unless it is known that T is IFoo (where T : IFoo)
```